# PHP quits Inkscape's shell mode too early

Tags: php, inkscape

I have a bunch of system generated SVGs files I need to convert to PDFs for further processing. SVGs are saved and processed by color, just in case someone's wondering. This is my conversion code:

```
$descspec = array(0 => array('pipe', 'r'),  // stdin
                  1 => array('pipe', 'w'),  // stdout
                  2 => array('pipe', 'w')); // stderr

// start Inkscape process
$process = proc_open('inkscape --shell', $descspec, $pipes);

foreach ($files as $color => $filearray) {

    foreach ($filearray as $filename) {

        $command = '"' . $path_to_svg . '" '.
                   '--export-area-drawing --export-text-to-path ' . 
                   '--export-pdf="' . $path_to_pdf . '"'

        fwrite($pipes[0], $command . "\n");
    }
}

fwrite($pipes[0], 'quit'."\n"); // leave shell mode
foreach ($pipes as $pipe) fclose($pipe);
proc_close($process); // close Inkscape
```

The problem is that this way, only about one third to half of the files get converted. My guess is that the second `foreach` loop terminates after just writing all the commands out to `stdin` without waiting for the conversion to finish, so that `quit` is issued and the Inkscape process is terminated before the whole conversion is done. Or a command is written to `stdin` while Inkscape isn't finished processing the previous command so that the second (and possibly even the third and fourth) one gets lost.

(Executing `system('inkscape ' . $command)` works and gets all files converted just fine, so I don't think the problem has something to do with the files. However, I would really really like to use Inkscape's shell mode so I don't have to start Inkscape (even with the `--without-gui` option) for every file.)

So if anyone could point me towards a solution I would very much appreciate it. How can I keep the process running until Inkscape has actually finished the conversion?

Comment: Is this the correct code? Because there is `.'` in the line `'--export-pdf="' . $path_to_pdf"'` missing?

Comment: The code is correct. As I mentioned, the command string works with `system()`. This must be due to my own sloppyness when simplifying the code for the SO post, I apologize. I'll fix that.

Comment: On which platform is this? have you tried running the exact same commands manually in a Inkscape shell?